# setting CSS class attribute by JQuery selector :hidden count

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have two sections, a `fieldset` panel `div`, and a "generated content" `div`.   I am "moving" elements from one to another by hiding them on change from one section and unhiding them in the other section.   For one particular section "Abstract", which has a class `.abstract` and several elements all having the class `oneseven`, how do I change the width attribute of the sections based on how many are hidden?

Here is my code:

```
// Abstract
//hide initially
    $('fieldset.abstract label').hide();
//individual Abstract elements Toggle Buttons
    //Currently on, turning Off
        $('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section > .oneseven > input').on('change', function () {
            var hidden = 0;
            var width = Number((1/(7-hidden))*100);
            if (this.checked) {
            } else {
                var hidden = ($('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section > :hidden').length + 1);
                var width = Number((1/(7-hidden))*100);
                console.log(hidden);
                console.log('"' + Number(width) + '%"');
/*issue here*/      $('.oneseven').css("width", '"' + Number(width) + '%"');
                var index = $(this).closest('section').prevAll('section').length;
                $('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section').eq(index).hide("slow");
                $('fieldset.abstract > label').eq(index+1).show("slow");
                $('fieldset.abstract > input').eq(index+1).prop('checked' , true);
            }
        });
    //Currently off, turning On
        $('fieldset.abstract > input').on('change', function () {
            var hidden = 0;
            var width = Number((1/(7-hidden))*100);
            if (this.checked) {
            } else {
                var hidden = ($('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section > :hidden').length - 1);
                var width = Number((1/(7-hidden))*100);
                console.log(hidden);
                console.log('"' + Number(width) + '%"');
/*and here*/        $('.oneseven').css("width", '"' + Number(width) + '%"');
                var index = $(this).prevAll('input').length;
                $('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section').eq(index-1).show("slow");
                $('.block > .abstract > .superseven > section > .oneseven > input').eq(index-1).prop('checked' , true);
                $('fieldset.abstract > label').eq(index).hide("slow");
            }
        });
```

I can accomplish this in the console by typing `$('.oneseven').css("width", "33.33%");`
 or changing the numeric value to `25%` or `20%`, etc...m but getting it in the JS section isn't working.

I have tried:

- type casting it into an int using parseInt()
- changing it to a `Number` using JS (current code)
- entering everything with the width actually in number format in the console and it works

I think it is somewhere in the second parameter for the css attribute Jquery selector.   How do I fixit?
*Notes*

I have the vars `hidden` and `width` twice, because I am not sure if they need to be global or not to solve this problem.   I am trying to get it to work, then I can troubleshoot and see what scope is needed.

Comment: Did you try getting rid of the nested quotes? I think `.css("width", width + "%")` should work.

Comment: you are correct, thanks!,   the final line of code is `$('.oneseven').css("width", (width) + "%");` with the `Number()` not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, @pimvdb is correct, for some reason, the nested quotes are not needed, so the final line of code is 
`$('.oneseven').css("width", (width) + "%");`

and the `Number()` type casting/conversions were not needed.

Comment: `Number` is only needed if you have e.g. a string which you want to convert. If you're doing calculations with `*` or `/` then you're guaranteed to get a number anyway.